# Запуск проекта без CrystalReports

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В проекте используются элементы CrystalReports. Но в моей студии он не установлен. Из за чего вылетает ошибка при запуске, на строчки из web конфига. Я решил проблему вырезанием из конфига строчек

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
```

Есть более изящный способ заставить всё заработать? Ну не считая докачки самого кристал репорта.

Comment: а чем вам загрузка не подходит ? 
если он установлен из нугета, то сделайте в консоли диспетчера пакетов dotnet restore или в обозревателе решений ПКМ по солюшну -> восстановить нугет

Comment: @Arthur он не установлен вообще. И если честно не сильно хочется. Похоже самый нормальный вариант просто как я написал, вырезать лишние строки.

Comment: если уверены, что он вам не пригодится - удалите его из нугета, чтобы не вырезать строки постоянно